# Two divs, static div on the left side and fluid div on the right side

Tags: html, static, width, fluid, css

Here's my situation:

```
   .left {
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
        height: 300px;
        margin-right: 20px
   }

  .right {
        float: right;
        max-width: 450px;
        height: 300px;
   }
```

I want the right div to be fluid, so when it comes to decreasing the width of browser it has to be still on the right side of the screen, but with smaller width.

But my right div is quite rude. Instead of doing what I'm telling him to do, he treats his width as his priority. When the window is touching his right edge, he's jumping below my poor left div instead of decreasing his width.

Do you guys know any way to punish him? To tell him that his behavior isn't RIGHT? To make him stay on the right side of the screen?

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following and that should be what you're looking for.

```
    .left {
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
        height: 300px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        border:1px solid black;
   }
  .right {
        max-width: 450px;
        height: 300px;
        border:1px solid black;
        margin-left:155px;
   }
```

If I remember correctly, floated div's cant have auto widths. So since your left div has a static width, you can just push your right div with a margin so it clears the left div and it will be fluid.